# How to specify that a digital file is for the purpose of printing.

Tags: word-choice, words

I would like to learn how to specify a type of file in Japanese. In an English context the common vernacular would be "...a print file". Is there a standardized way to say this in Japanese that would sound natural in a design/printing industry context?

"....のファイル"

I am worried that "プリント" isn't the right word.
I also don't want the verb: :刷る" or the noun: "写り"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the printing industry, but I would probably use something simple like 印刷用.

印刷 is the real Japanese word for printing.
用 is a useful little kanji that basically means "for the purpose of".

You can say 印刷用紙 to mean printing paper, or perhaps in your case 印刷用ファイル.

Answer (score 0):

"**印刷用** ファイル" is formal and perfect, "**印刷** ファイル" is also used, and both are technical terms.
"**印刷用の** ファイル" makes sense but it is not a technical term and is used to explain the purpose of the file/files.